# laravel custom validation return empty errors when I defined it in the ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, custom-validators

When I defined a custom validation in the Validated Service Provider. And when it is failed I got empty MessageBox. I don't understand why it is happens.

**UPDATED:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::extend('custom_validation', function ( $attribute, $value, $parameters ) {
            return false;
        } );
    }
}
```

in the controller

```
private function isValid()
{
    $this->validation = Validator::make( $this->attributes, [
       'input' => 'custom_validation'
    ] );

    dd($this->validation->errors()); //returned 
    // MessageBag{#668 #messages: [] #format: ":message" }
```

}
    }

**UPDATE2:**
my app.php file

```
'providers' => [
...
    App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: Perhaps share come code of your custom validation to elaborate?

Comment: done. I use laravel 5.1

Comment: is `custom_validation` message i.e. response when error occurred defined somewhere? Maybe add to you validation.php file

Comment: sorry guys, it was the stupid question. Validation working properly!

Answer (score 0):

To create a Custom Validator: 
Step 1:

```
-> Create a Service provide php aritsan make:proider ValidatorServiceProvider
```

Step 2: add the following to your service provider in boot method

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('custom_validation', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

        //checks if input value is 1
       if($value = 1) return true;

        return false;
    });
}
```

Step 3:
Register your service provide to config/app.php in provider section

```
    App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class
```

Step 4 (Laravel way)
Create a request to validate all of your input field

```
php artisan make:request CustomValidationRequest
```

Step 5:
Add the following to the request

```
//validation rules
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'digit'  =>  'required|custom_validation'
    ];
}

//message
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'digit.required'    =>  'This value is required.',
        'digit.custom_validation'  =>  'This custom validation is required'
    ];
}
```

Now use it in you controller

```
public function store(Request CustomValidationRequest)
{
  //validation will be done and send back to view if error occurred
}
```

Hopefully this will help
Cheers

Comment: I also put this to the app.php config

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using the laravel Validator facade ? 
if so you do not  need to define it from the service provider?

Comment: You must answer the question!