# Is it possible to use the "sometimes" Validator method in a FormRequest class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) don't make it clear whether or not you can use the `sometimes` method anywhere other than as an inline declaration inside a controller method. For a form with a large number of fields, it makes sense to decouple it into a `FormRequest`. But I'm not sure if it is possible to use `sometimes` here. Does anyone know if it is possible or how?

Perhaps adding `$this->sometimes(...args);` to a `__construct()` method?

All I can think of so far is something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->getValidatorInstance()->sometimes(['email', 'phone'], 'required', function ($input) {
        return true; // arbitrary logic here
    });
}
```

But I get the error: `exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function make() on null' in <project_root>/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php:77` to do with a `Container` interface.

Comment: you could add `'email'=>'sometime|email'` to rules within `FormRequest`

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol Sorry, it's not as simple as this - I should've been more explicit. I want to write a custom sometimes validator with an anonymous function.

Comment: this my help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286037/laravel-custom-validation-return-empty-errors-when-i-defined-it-in-the-servicepr/40286750#40286750

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'sometimes|email',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not as simple as this - I should've been more explicit. I want to write a custom sometimes validator with an anonymous function.